# How to adjust v-simple-table column width in Vuetify.js component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have used vuetify.js as my latest projects UI component.
I try to adjust width of v-simple-table of th,td using css,
but nothing happen.
I want to adjust every th,td width 50px.
So I made code at [codepen](https://codepen.io/takopon25258989/pen/MWOVxJm) and like below.

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card width="500px">
     <v-simple-table>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left" v-for="n in 20">
              {{n}}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td v-for="n in 20">{{ n }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
   </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th,td {
  width: 50px !important;
}
</style>
```

I thought that css pass is effective to width, but never change.
How do I adjust width of v-simple-table?
Does anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your style to

```
min-width: 50px !important;
```